# Removing a UILabel programmatically after a button is pressed

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to create/show a label when a button is pressed, and then delete/hide the same label when the same button is pressed again. I am trying to do this all programmatically in Swift.

I have tried using label.removeFromSuperview() but it doesn't seem to have any effect. However when i try removing the button in the same code location using button.removeFromSuperview()

```
var label = UILabel()
let labelImage = UIImage(named: "Strike Line.png")


/* to select checkmarked state */
func pressCheck() {

    let image = UIImage(named: "Checkmark.png")
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressUnCheck), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


    textField1.textColor = UIColor.gray //change textfield to a gray color

    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x : 31, y : 69, width: 200, height: 2))

    label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: labelImage!)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}


func pressUnCheck()
{
    let image = UIImage(named: "To Be Completed Circle.png")
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.pressCheck), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)


    label.removeFromSuperview()
    textField1.textColor = UIColor.black

}
```

Here is where i am trying to remove/hide the label.

Comment: Can you show more code like where you create the label and where you add it?

Comment: are you sure this code is being executed?

Comment: added more code. @JohnnyAW yes i believe it is being executed because when i try label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red it will change my label image to have a red color when the button is clicked

Comment: hmm, a possible problem could be, that you don't remove old buttons, so if you click on the "wrong" button, you will call the same function over and over again. That means, that you will not call your expected function. Additional, you would lose the reference to a `label` if you call `pressCheck` twice

Comment: I wouldn't remove the label, instead simply hide it. Much safer, and as @JohnnyAW pointed out, repeatedly setting isHidden doesn't cause issues.

Comment: Try adding `button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)` before you add a new target to the button. If that is the same button you are adding multiple targets to it. Both will get called on each tap.

Comment: @MicahWilson I think you were right! I never removed the buttons, i just added new targets, but kept the same old targets as well. I added the line of code you suggested, before adding my new targets and now the label.isHidden = true makes it work great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this apparently was the fix I'll drop it in as an answer.

Add `button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)` before you add any new targets to your button.

If you don't remove the current target it'll have multiple targets and be calling both `pressCheck()` and `pressUnCheck()` on each button press.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to handle this... If you just want to hide it you can use

label.isHidden = true - would hide the label. 
label.isHidden = false -  would show the label.